# Retrieve / send back HTTP headers with PHP / Curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies, http-headers

I have a HTML/PHP/JS page that I use for an automation process.

On load, it performs a curl request like :

```
function get_data($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
$html = get_data($url);
```

Then it uses DOMDocument to retrieve a specific element on the remote page. My PHP code handles it, makes some operations, then stores it in a variable.

My purpose as you can guess is to simulate a "normal" connexion. To do so, I used the Tamper tool to see what requests are performed, when I was physically interacting with the remote page. HTTP headers are made of UA, cookies (among them, a session cookie), and so on. The only POST variable I have to send back is my PHP variable (you know, the one wich was calculated and stored in a PHP var). I also tested the process with Chrome, which allows me to copy/paste requests as curl.

My question is simple : is there a way to handle HTTP requests / cookies in a simple way ? Or do I have to retrieve them, parse them, store them and send them back "one by one" ?

Indeed, a request and a response are slightly different, but in this case they share many things in common. So I wonder if there is a way to explore the remote page as a browser would do, and interact with it, using for instance an extra PHP library.

Or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way and I should use other languages (PERL...) ?

The code shown above does not handle requests and cookies, I've tried but it was a bit too tricky to handle, hence I ask this question here :) I'm not lazy, but I wonder if there is a more simple way to achieve my goal.

Thanks for your advices, sorry for the english

Comment: you mean, make php act as if it was a browser and fetch everything a page uses (css, js, blah blah blah?)? No. there's no simple way.

Comment: maybe not something extreme like that, but a way to handle those requests in an easier way